# How do I load css files for different locales in jsp?

Tags: jsp

I would like to load different css files for different locals.  For example, if the current locale is English, then I want to load `"main.css"` file. However, if the current locale is Russian then I want to load `"main_ru.css"` file.

How do I do it in jsp?

Comment: Why do you have different stylesheets for different cultures/locales? A stylesheet should be universal, it is content that should be changed, so I'm genuinely curious as to why you're doing this.

Comment: Well for example some words will be longer like `book` and `забронировать` and so the block for example or button will be bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main_${theCurrentLocale}.css">
```

And it's of course up to you to store the current locale in the `theCurrentLocale` request or session attribute.